# Параллельная отрисовка в OpenGL

Tags: delphi, opengl

Есть массив координат треугольников, как параллельно отрисовать их.

Пример кода который нужно распараллелить:

```
  glLineWidth(5);

  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex2f (Projection[Triangle[1]][1]/1000, Projection[Triangle[1]][2]/1000);
    glVertex2f (Projection[Triangle[2]][1]/1000, Projection[Triangle[2]][2]/1000);
    glVertex2f (Projection[Triangle[3]][1]/1000, Projection[Triangle[3]][2]/1000);
    glVertex2f (Projection[Triangle[1]][1]/1000, Projection[Triangle[1]][2]/1000);
  glEnd;

  SwapBuffers(FDC);
```

Comment: Что такое параллельная отрисовка в вашем понимании? И для решения какой задачи она вам нужна?

Comment: Вместо устаревшей fixed-function pipeline используйте шейдеры и вершинные буферы. Тогда все эти треугольники будут отрисовываться за одну операцию максимально параллельно.

Comment: Я рисую треугольники в цикле, что очень долго, мне необходимо передать весь массив OpenGL, что бы он сам максимально быстро разобрался с данной задачей

Comment: Может у вас имеется пример кода?

Answer (score 0):

```
  glLineWidth(5);
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, @ProjectionOfVertex[0]);
  glDrawElements(GL_LINES, Length(VertexIndexes), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, VertexIndexes);
  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  SwapBuffers(FDC);
```